# *(int *)foo VS (int *)*foo. Whats the difference between these two?

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I am working on RTOS project and I'm trying to pass struct type typecasted to void pointer to thread function and derefernce that void pointer using typecast to same struct type. I was getting error when trying to do it this way `(eUartDriver_t*) *args`. Then found on the internet to use `*(eUartDriver_t*) args` , but it didn't explained the difference and why does it work

Comment: What is `args`? What error did you get? What is the expected result of that statement?

Comment: Order of operations matters a lot. `*args` dereferences the pointer, so casting that to another pointer type afterwards may not be possible (since the result is possibly not a pointer type)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `args` is declared to be a `void *`. The expression `*args` means “the thing `args` points to,” so `*args` would be a `void`, but `void` is not a usable type. So `*args` is bad code, and the compiler complains.

`(eUartDriver_t *) args` says “Convert the value of `args` to `eUartDriver_t *`”. That type is a pointer to an `eUartDriver_t`. The result of this conversion is a pointer to an `eUartDriver_t`, so applying `*`, as in `* (eUartDriver_t *) args`, refers to a `eUartDriver_t`, which is a usable type.

Comment: so expression (eUartDriver_t *) *args isn't valid at all in C ?

Answer (score 0):

@UnholySheep

> Order of operations matters a lot. *args dereferences the pointer, so casting that to another pointer type afterwards may not be possible (since the result is possibly not a pointer type)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  //Consider integer:
  int x;
  //And pointer to it.
  int *p= &x;
  
  //These expressions
  p; &x;
  //are of type int*, which means the dereferencing operator can be used on these.
  //This is legal:
  *p; *(&x); p[0];
  
  //Pointer casting <==> reinterpretation of pointer (address)
  //These expressions are almost the same (have the same values and storage space)
  (int*)p; (char*)p; p; (void*)p;
  
  /*The only difference is in dereferencing or artmetics, which must happen 
  AFTER the pointer is known as (new) type pointer.
  
  So once you've got this expression:*/
  (char*)p;
  //or new variable:
  char *newP= (char*)p;
  //or macro:
  #define newP (char*)p
  
  //THAN you can do derefrencing with proper use of operators *ptr or ptr[offset]
  *newP; *((char*)p); newP[0]; ((char*)p)[0];
}
```